# When to run a python script by "python -m module-name"?

Tags: python-2.7

This post is about ways to run a python script.

```
python -m module-name
```

searches sys.path for the named module and runs the corresponding .py file as a script.

what are its advantage and disadvantage compared to run the script
`module-name.py` explicitly as either `python module-name.py` or `module-name.py`?

When to use which way to run a python script?

Comment: More convenience than anything, imo. Easier to say `python -m timeit "..."` than to hunt down your system's copy of timeit.py. Though there's also the matter that some modules are also packages.

Answer (score 3):

You've mentioned one of them already:

> searches sys.path for the named module

This means you don't have to explicitly give the full path when using a module found in, say, the standard library.

It also allows you to run a submodule as the main script:

```
python -m foo.bar
```

This will cause the main script to run as a package meaning that relative imports can be used from the main script. This is useful when the submodule performs some task used by or auxiliary to the "main" program which should be performed discretely/independently.